# Excel add link name to hyperlink

Tags: excel

How to change the link name

`=HYPERLINK("http://"&D5&"/root/data/trend.csv")`

`=HYPERLINK("http://"&D5&"/root/data/trend.csv","NAME")`

Does not work.

Comment: Works in 2106...what version of Excel are you using? Do you get an error or other message?  One idea: you might need to put a single-quote at the beginning of D5 to make it text and not a URL or UNC

Comment: Are you sure that's where your file is located? When opening a file through a web browser it is typically preceded with `file:///`, not `http://`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have a problem with Excel. Try this:

> (1) Run regedit.exe
>
> (2) Navigate to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT -> jpegfile -> CLSID
>
> (3) Right-click on “Default” (the Value Name) and select “Modify”
>
> (4) Change “Value data” from {25336920-03F9-11cf-8FD0-00AA00686F13} to
>   {FFE2A43C-56B9-4bf5-9A79-CC6D4285608A}

It's solved [here](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/741815-hyperlink-not-showing-friendly-name.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with the link, notice:

=HYPERLINK("http://"&D5&"/root/data/trend.csv","NAME")

"http://" -> the formula understands this is your hyperlink

&D5& -> now it understands you are trying to do an addition of the hyperlink to whatever it is in cell 'D5' and the following: "/root/data/trend.csv"

I am not sure if this is intended, but excel will not be able to process the formula like that. Suggestion:
Type the link in a cell and use that cell as reference, ex:

A1 `="http://"&D5&"/root/data/trend.csv"`

D5 `="text here"`

```
=Hyperlink(A1, "Name")
```

I hope this solves your problem.